# How to make k8s allocate gpu/npu devices following specific rule

Tags: go, kubernetes, plugins, gpu, scheduling

I have multiple gpu cards within one machine, and I need to let the k8s allocate gpu/npus device following some rules I set.

For example, supposing there are 8 gpu cards whose id is from 0-7, and only device0、device1、device6 and device7 are available. Now I need to create one pod with 2 devices, these two devices must be either of (device0, device1) or (device6, device7). Other device combinations such as (device0, device6) are not valid.

Is there any way to do that?  I am using kubernetes of version 1.18 and implemented my own device plugin.

Comment: where will you write those rules? to use specific gpus, you could set `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` env instead of using `nvidia.com/gpu` resource request for pod, that's what [nvidia k8s device plugin does](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/blob/8732b2f668074a83562a5d17c94fe7f8c4e34f7c/server.go#L224-L226).

Comment: from custom device plugin or custom device manager or what ever, anything that I can achieve it @abuccts

Comment: so you write something like `"gpu/rule": "smaller than 4"` in pod spec and use a device plugin to parse that rule? you can either set the `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` env to `0,1,2` in pod spec directly without using device plugin, or modify the [Allocate function](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/blob/8732b2f668074a83562a5d17c94fe7f8c4e34f7c/server.go#L225): get the request rule `"smaller than 4"` and set `m.allocateEnvvar: "0,1,2"`.

Comment: what do you mean "modify the allocate funcition"? which module does this allocate function belongs, device plugin or device manager?  could you give more details?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why would you write a rule like this:

> every device-id be smaller than 4

If you want to limit the amount of GPUs you should be using `limits` and `requests` which is nicely explained on [Schedule GPUs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/).
So you can just limit the resource to only 4 GPUs like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cuda-vector-add
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
    - name: cuda-vector-add
      # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.7.11/test/images/nvidia-cuda/Dockerfile
      image: "k8s.gcr.io/cuda-vector-add:v0.1"
      resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 4 # requesting 1 GPU
```

If you have different types of GPUs on different nodes you can use `labels` which you can read here [Clusters containing different types of GPUs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#clusters-containing-different-types-of-gpus).

> ```sh
> # Label your nodes with the accelerator type they have.
> kubectl label nodes <node-with-k80> accelerator=nvidia-tesla-k80
> kubectl label nodes <node-with-p100> accelerator=nvidia-tesla-p100
> ```

If your nodes are running different versions of GPUs, then use Node Labels and Node Selectors to schedule pods to appropriate GPUs. Following is an illustration of this workflow:

As part of your Node bootstrapping, identify the GPU hardware type on your nodes and expose it as a node label.

```
NVIDIA_GPU_NAME=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader --id=0)
source /etc/default/kubelet
KUBELET_OPTS="$KUBELET_OPTS --node-labels='alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu-name=$NVIDIA_GPU_NAME'"
echo "KUBELET_OPTS=$KUBELET_OPTS" > /etc/default/kubelet
```

Specify the GPU types a pod can use via Node Affinity rules.

```
kind: pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/affinity: >
      {
        "nodeAffinity": {
          "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
            "nodeSelectorTerms": [
              {
                "matchExpressions": [
                  {
                    "key": "alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu-name",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values": ["Tesla K80", "Tesla P100"]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
spec: 
  containers: 
    - 
      name: gpu-container-1
      resources: 
        limits: 
          alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu: 2
```

This will ensure that the pod will be scheduled to a node that has a Tesla K80 or a Tesla P100 Nvidia GPU.

You could find other relevant information on [unofficial-kubernetes Scheduling gpus](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/).

Comment: the nodeSelector is for selecting node which has devices of 
the same type and doesn't fit my requirement that picking up specific device from different versions within same machine

Comment: e.g. I have 8 gpu cards in one machine, and they are of different versions. Due to some reason, I need to pick up some of them before mounting them to container by some selection rule

Comment: nodeAffinity on Node Labels and Node Selectors is for different versions. Please read the docs.

Comment: difference versions between different nodes, or between different 
gpu devices of one node? The later case is what I need here.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the first case from my understanding. But you can test it yourself and post an answer that will be helpful to the community.